# batch file command to compare newest file and output differences

Tags: batch-file, cmd, compare, diff

I have the below code which someone gave to me but I don't know how to put it together in a bat file so it runs successfully.

The aim is to find the latest (last modified) file in c:/ and compare it with c:/2.txt and output the differences into c:/786.txt

```
 cd /d c:\
 for /f %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d /tw') do (set latest=%%a & goto :eof)

 for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (
  'diff c:\%latest% c:\2.txt ^| findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>"'
 ) do @echo %%b >>c:\786.txt
```

Can someone please put this code together for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /d c:\
set "latest="
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d /tw') do (set "latest=%%a" & goto :found)
:found
if not defined latest exit /b
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (
    'diff "c:\%latest%" "c:\2.txt" ^| findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>"'
) do (
    >> "c:\786.txt" echo(%%b
)
```

Ordering by date descending, the latest file is the first, so on first iteration assign the file name and exit of the `for` loop.

Then check if any file has been found. It not, end of the script

If we have a file, compare latest file against the indicated one and send the filtered lines to the final file.

EDIT - Refactor code to made it more usable and adapt to comments. Search for last file in folder moved to a subroutine.

```dos
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getLatestFileInFolder "c:\" latestC
    call :getLatestFileInFolder "d:\" latestD

    if not defined latestC ( echo NO File in C & exit /b )
    if not defined latestD ( echo NO File in D & exit /b )

    for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (
        'diff "%latestC%" "%latestD%" ^| findstr /r /c:"^<" /c:"^>"'
    ) do (
        >> "c:\786.txt" echo(%%b
    )

    endlocal
    exit /b

:getLatestFileInFolder folderToSearch variableToReturn
    setlocal
    set "folder=%~1" & if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"
    set "latest="
    pushd "%folder%"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d /tw 2^>nul') do (set "latest=%%~fa" & goto :latestFileFound)
    :latestFileFound
    popd
    endlocal & set "%~2=%latest%" & goto :eof
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to adjust the code so 2.txt is also the latest file in d:\